# Cómo saltar o solucionar error al leer imagen .tif con PIL en Python

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

Estoy tratando de hacer OCR a muchas imágenes .tif (por lote) y guardar en .txt con tesseract, pytesseract y con la ayuda de PIL para abrir las imágenes a procesar. Estas imágenes se encuentran dentro de muchas carpetas, el código funciona bien con la mayoría de imágenes pero a veces se encuentra con una que no puede abrir, leer o identificar y se para el programa.

¿Cómo saltar ese error y que continúe el programa? ¿O hay alguna otra solución?

**Nota:** Revisé la ruta y es correcta, la imagen es .tif abre y se visualiza correctamente.

**Parte del código**

```
imagenes = os.listdir(f"G:/OCR2/Orfeo/{elemento}")
    for elemento2 in imagenes:
        '''Como puede que exista un archivo de imagen no compatible con Tesseract
        validamos que tenga la extensión deseada para que lo procese, de lo contrario
        se saltará el archivo sin procesarlo evitando un error en la ejecución del
        programa.
        '''
        validacion_archivo = ".tif" in elemento2
        if validacion_archivo == True:
            # Ruta donde está instalado Pytesseract
            pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
            # Ruta de los archivos de imagen, se concatena elemento y elemento 2 para armar la ruta
            
            # Aquí es donde se presenta el error
            imagen = Image.open(f"G:/OCR2/Orfeo/{elemento}/{elemento2}")
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(imagen, lang='spa')
            print('Texto: ', text)
            
            
            # Guardamos resultado en un archivo .txt, en la carpeta nueva creada en la raíz Convertidos
            conversion = str(elemento2)
            concatenado = conversion + extension
            file = open(f"G:/OCR2/Convertidos/{elemento}/{concatenado}", "w")
            file.write(text)
            file.close()
    print(f"Carpeta {elemento} finalizada")
```

**Error en consola**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "G:\OCR2\Orfeo\Script Tesseract OCR.py", line 39, in 
> imagen = Image.open(f"G:/OCR2/Orfeo/{elemento}/{elemento2}")
> File "C:\Users\sis012.server\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3147, in open
> raise UnidentifiedImageError(
> PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'G:/OCR2/Orfeo/carpeta 1/f492779520.tif'

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado con el manejo de errores a través de Try; Except?

```
imagenes = os.listdir(f"G:/OCR2/Orfeo/{elemento}")
    for elemento2 in imagenes:
        '''Como puede que exista un archivo de imagen no compatible con Tesseract
        validamos que tenga la extensión deseada para que lo procese, de lo contrario
        se saltará el archivo sin procesarlo evitando un error en la ejecución del
        programa.
        '''
        validacion_archivo = ".tif" in elemento2
        if validacion_archivo == True:
            try:
                # Ruta donde está instalado Pytesseract
                pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
                # Ruta de los archivos de imagen, se concatena elemento y elemento 2 para armar la ruta
                
                # Aquí es donde se presenta el error
                imagen = Image.open(f"G:/OCR2/Orfeo/{elemento}/{elemento2}")
                text = pytesseract.image_to_string(imagen, lang='spa')
                print('Texto: ', text)
                
                
                # Guardamos resultado en un archivo .txt, en la carpeta nueva creada en la raíz Convertidos
                conversion = str(elemento2)
                concatenado = conversion + extension
                file = open(f"G:/OCR2/Convertidos/{elemento}/{concatenado}", "w")
                file.write(text)
                file.close()
            except:
                continue
    print(f"Carpeta {elemento} finalizada")
```

Si no funciona, puedes probar también con finally o en vez de `continue` poner `pass`

```
try:
    .
    .
    .
finally:
    continue
    # pass
```

Comment: Te recomiendo evitar los "fallos silenciosos" dentro de lo posible (try: ... except: (codigo sin efecto)). Pues ese código captura todos los fallos, incluso los inesperados (como un valueerror)

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias. Quizás esté bien para comprobar que efectivamente el código funciona y salta ese error y después analizar más profundamente por qué ocurre y solucionarlo por otros medios.